# Run a script every hour on a specific day

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, apscheduler

I want to use the Advanced Python Scheduler (https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) in order to scrape popular times from Google every hour (40 grocery stores in list markets, from 6:00 to 18:00) on a specific day.

My code works if I start it manually every hour, but I don't know how to write correct code in order to start the AP Scheduler. It was running for quite some time, but the resulting data frame was empty.

I was looking into the manual and other questions, but I couldn't figure out how to write the code.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

def job():
    for market in markets:
        data = livepopulartimes.get_populartimes_by_address(market)
        current_popularity_ = pd.DataFrame([[date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), 
                           date.today().strftime("%A"),
                           datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"),
                           pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index').loc['current_popularity'].values[0]
                          ]],
             columns=['date','day','time','value'])
        current_popularity_['market'] = market
        current_popularity = current_popularity.append(current_popularity_)

sched = BlockingScheduler()

sched.add_job(
    job, 
    trigger='cron',
    hour='06-18',
    start_date = '2021-02-04',
    end_date = '2021-02-04'
)

sched.start()
```

Comment: can you explain why you want to use this instead of a more standard solution? (on Windows: scheduled tasks. On Linux/Mac: cron. On AWS: lambda, etc)

Comment: You are saying the script was running correctly for some time, but stopped without you changing anything?

Comment: _but the resulting data frame was empty_ - maybe you should fix this instead if you say it was running fine before. A scheduler won't fix your api call (other than it retrying)

Comment: The `end_date` arguments has a value already in the past. Does it mean the scheduler runs forever, or it never runs?

Comment: The `start_date` and `end_date` values don't make any sense since they indicate the schedule should end 10 years earlier than it should start. Also the fact that they're both in the past mean the schedule will never run.

Comment: @AdamSmith: Thanks. As I mentioned, I don't have any clue about this. I will look into cron.

Comment: @goalie1998 I stopped the script manually, there weren't any error messages.

Comment: @OneCricketeer: The dataframe isn't empty if I run the main part of the code manually every hour.

Comment: OMG, I haven't checked the dates! Indeed, I wanted to run the script on 2021-01-07. Shame on me...

Answer (score 1):

So I corrected the dates in my code and tried to run it again.
But again, it didn't work. The resulting data frame was empty.
The code works if I start it manually (data frame is not empty).
So if anyone has an idea what is wrong with the code for the scheduler, please let me know.

Comment: Same problem here - its not the dates